# Kubernetes and Spring Boot Actuator, best practice for running application and management on different ports?

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, spring-boot-actuator

In our application we have been separating the `management.server.port` and the `server.port` so we can expose the web server easily via Ingress and Service objects and keep the management port only for the Kubernetes `liveness` and `readiness` probes.

However, in the documentation for Actuator there is this warning:

> If your Actuator endpoints are deployed on a separate management context, be aware that endpoints are then not using the same web infrastructure (port, connection pools, framework components) as the main application. In this case, a probe check could be successful even if the main application does not work properly (for example, it cannot accept new connections).

Is there a best practice here? Is it just to implement my own readiness check?

Comment: Why not just block access to that path on the ingress instead of running a different port?

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: It depends on the ingress type, they are all configured differently.

Comment: I don't know any type where this works.

Comment: @MoritzSchmitzv.Hülst I am trying to find answer for same question. Did you find some answers for this? Would be happy to know them.

Comment: @chaosguru Unfortunately not, no.